Ubuntu 24.04 freezing every time external HDD plugged in
I'm working with two tower PCs running desktop versions of Ubuntu, one (old PC) running Ubuntu 20.04.6 and one (new PC) running a fresh install of 24.04.1. I also have a 3TB external USB drive (Seagate Expansion portable hard drive, 1TEAPG-500) that I used to back up most of /home from the old PC to be transferred to the new one.
The external drive is currently formatted as NTFS and is powered by a single USB. It works perfectly fine on the old Ubuntu PC, but every time I plug it into the new PC, Ubuntu freezes and does not respond to anything but a manual shutdown. I've tried exiting the GUI to terminal, unplugging the external drive, and just leaving the system to sit for an hour, but it stays frozen no matter what. I've also tried deleting the .Trash folder from the external drive as per suggestions on some other threads, but that didn't make a difference.
The freeze happens the instant the drive is plugged in, so I don't have any time to try to diagnose it prior to mounting. I've tried using different USB ports on the new PC in case it was a power supply issue, ensuring that the ports were 3.0, but no luck there either. (On top of that, it works on the older PC even when plugged into a 2.0 USB port.)
The new PC has two internal drives, a 250G SSD and a 1TB HDD, and I followed the directions here to move /home to /dev/sdb1 on the HDD while the core of Ubuntu remains on the SSD. There don't appear to be any issues as long as the external drive isn't plugged in, so I don't know if that setup has anything to do with what's going on.
Are there any diagnostics I could run while the USB drive is plugged into the old PC that might give some insight into why the new PC is freezing up?

If your machine is a laptop, or the external drive is getting power from your USB to operate; the problem with the 24.04 machine maybe hardware related (ie. PSU lacking power; you do mention this though) and not related to the OS installed... You mention releases, but give no clear product details (Server, Desktop etc) and don't rule out other possible causes such as marginal PSU in provided details.   If it was related to software (ie. Ubuntu) I'd expect SysRq or logs to provide clues even if unclean shutdown; but did you try clean shutdown using SysRq etc.

All PSUs have a power they're rated at providing when new (specific number of watts at specific voltages) but as they age what they can provide reduces & they soon can't provide what they were rated at (when new). This shouldn't occur on a new box (or first year) but if you're close to the maximum draw failure is sooner; the life of the PSU will be longer (usually) if your usage is far less than PSU max. This is all hardware related though. Did you try logging into text terminal or have it show details PRIOR to connection, or SysRq commands (ie. bypass any dead GUI) etc

If the external drive has its own power supply (ie. isn't drawing power from USB cable) your machine PSU shouldn't be a problem; but we're limited to details you provide.

If you open a Terninal before attaching the external drive; might it be possible to enter commands there, AFTER the attachment; e.g. dmesg | less for starters? FWIW: I have avoided NTFS for Linux use for long, due to severe problems with an external drive a few years back. I got the impression that Windows use(s/d) some trickery(?) that might not be supported by the Linux driver(s). All shared drives/mem-sticks kept VFAT/exFAT, 7zip/Rar/pkzip used for transferring with kept file attributes.

NTFS not recommended, you lose ownership & permissions. If just /home you can reset them, but if any system partitions very difficult to reset as not all are root. Are both systems on same network? If so you can easily use scp or rsync. I was even able to scp a folder from my Windows system to my desktop.

The drive maybe hanging due to lack of power being supplied from the PC, and the PC is just waiting for the drive to complete commands it accepted at the start of comms (ie. your issue is power related due to old device & USB powered device - connect an external power source to the drive and you may find the issue is gone).

@Hannu yeah unfortunately it's a shared drive, so to change it to exfat I'd have to move all of the data off of it, reformat it, and then put everything back. It's on my to-do list but way at the bottom, esp since this is the first Ubuntu machine it's had problems with.

@guiverc It seems like I can mount it just fine from the command line, so I think it's something specific to the GUI.

@oldfred Decided to try ad-hoc wifi after all but the 20.04 PC doesn't have any options to create a new network under the network manager, time for a new post

If sharing with a Windows machine, better to use NTFS than exFAT or FAT. NTFS has journal. But you must make sure Windows does not turn fast start up on which sets hibernation flag. That prevents the Linux NTFS driver from writing to prevent data loss when Windows restores hiberfile.

As per @guiverc's recommendation, switching out of the GUI to the command line before plugging in the external drive worked.
From there I used fdisk -l to find the drive and ran sudo mount -tv ntfs /dev/sdh2 /media to mount the partition that contained the data.
The command line mount completes successfully without any errors, so I can complete my file transfers from there, although the GUI still freezes if I switch back to it.

$ udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdh2  will mount your disk in the same style as "the OS" does - this info might help track down where the problem is.

@Hannu I actually just got another freeze when trying to open the file manager without the external drive being plugged in, so looks like this issue might go deeper and the drive was just exacerbating it somehow.
